# An error occurred during pricing of a detail line item

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to add a SalesOrder to MS Dynamics Online 2011. Although my line items come through, the order fails to calculate the total:

[image]

[image]

**I notice that extended amount is never calculated**. When I click lock pricing, the amounts calculate. LockPricing is a read only property in my code. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/C6cqxxmx

Comment: probably the products are not defined in the price list that you specified

Comment: I cannot seem to add any products to a price list. When I go to default price list, I don't see any options. I add one and click save and close. I still do not see any. Do I need to create invoices instead of sales orders?

Comment: you need to open the Price List and add the price list items. If inside quote/order/invoice there are line items with products not mapped inside the selected price list CRM can't calculate the total and normally display that error. I also made a screenshot http://i40.tinypic.com/34igt1t.jpg

Comment: Thanks here is the code:       ProductPriceLevel newPriceListItem1 = new ProductPriceLevel
                {
                    PriceLevelId = new CrmEntityReference(PriceLevel.LogicalName, PriceLevel.Id),
                    ProductId = new CrmEntityReference(p.LogicalName, p.ProductId.Value),
                    UoMId =  new CrmEntityReference(_serviceContext.UoMSet.FirstOrDefault().LogicalName, _serviceContext.UoMSet.FirstOrDefault().Id),
                    Amount = p.Price,
                };

                Guid _priceListItem1Id = _serviceContext.Create(newPriceListItem1);